# ¿Cómo resolver superposición de audios con MediaPlayer en Android?

Tags: java, android, mediaplayer

Buenas, estoy haciendo una app en Android Studio, para reproducir audios de mi carpeta raw en la app. El problema es que cuando doy click a un audio se reproduce, y, si antes de que termine el audio doy click a otro sonido se intercalan y no se como hacer parar al primer audio. ¿A qué función podría recurrir para resolver esto? Un saludo chicos/as. Aquí va parte de mi codigo:

```
final MediaPlayer sound2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio2);

    Button button2 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            sound2.start();
        }
    });


    final MediaPlayer sound3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio3);

    Button button3 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button3);

    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            sound3.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: [Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/android-studio/info): Utilizar esta etiqueta solo si la pregunta está asociada al uso, funcionalidades o problemas con el IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te aconsejo utilizar la misma propiedad para el [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) y así poder parar y eliminar antes de ejecutar cualquiera.

```
public class CustomActivity extends Activity {

    private MediaPlayer mp = null;

    private void createAudio(int resource) {
        if (this.mp != null) {
            this.mp.stop();
            this.mp.release();
            this.mp = null;
        }
        return this.mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resource);
    }

    public void onCustomClick() {
        final MediaPlayer audio = this.createAudio(R.raw.audio2);
        audio.start();
    }

    public void onAnotherCustomClick() {
        final MediaPlayer audio = this.createAudio(R.raw.audio3);
        audio.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Si añadiese audio4, audio5, etc, los creo en varios métodos onAnotherCustomClick() ?

Comment: No hace falta, el ejemplo era demostrativo, puedes utilizar un método que haga esas 2 líneas que hago en esos métodos de click y llamarlo desde los métodos que necesites.

Comment: Muchas gracias dddenis, me ha servido